# How to stop an Azure Process that has locked my AppService AppSettings and never ends?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am in the process of migrating from a MYSQL InApp Database to an Azure MySQL Database instance. I used the Export feature of the InApp DB and it worked fine. The tables appeared in my standalone MYSQL Database.

However, very surprisingly it also automatically updated the app AppSetting connectionstring which is not cool. This is not a bug but definitely not ideal IMO.

Now I want to change the AppSetting MySQL connection string BACK to the InApp database, but I cannot save any changes on the AppService Configuration screen - it always throws this exception below. This means I am stuck. Is there any way to see the running processes in Azure and cancel one for an AppService?

Cannot modify this site because another operation is in progress. Details: Id: 18133820-74e1-41eb-a748-9008252xxxx, OperationName: MigrateMySql, CreatedTime: 10/13/2019 2:21:20 AM, WebSystemName: websites, SubscriptionName: yyyyyyy-cf98-4011-b14a-905062f4aa23, WebspaceName: xxxxxebspace, SiteName: data-driven, SlotName: Production, ServerFarmName: , GeoOperationId: (null)

Comment: I think, in your case, the best solution is to create a support ticket from Azure Portal, they will able to provide you more information about the status of the process and  help you to stop it if needed

Comment: Thanks - I have done this too - I was just wondering if anyone has come across it.

Comment: Ok, after roughly an hour the process was unlocked... so there must be some sort of timeout on rogue processes...

Comment: Did you do anything to solve it, if yes you could post your solution to help others.

Comment: No, nothing I did unlocked it, see above, I think it was an internal timeout